# Unexpected behavior from Jest mockImplementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have code that I am writing tests for to refactor later, as such I cannot change the code or any of the dependencies. Here is the problem:

```js
// foo.js
Knex = require('knex')

module.exports ={func}
// calling this inside func will 
// have the expected {a:4}
client = Knex()


async function func(){
  console.log(client)
  return true
}
```

```js
// foo.spec.js
const foo = require('./foo')
const Knex = require('knex')
jest.mock('knex', ()=>jest.fn())

describe('jest.mockImplementation',()=>{
  it('should mock knex',async ()=>{
    Knex.mockImplementation(()=>({a:4}))
    // alternative, I can put
    // const foo = require('./foo')
    // here
    await foo.func()
  })
})
```

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports={
  "verbose": true,
  "testEnvironment": "node",
}
```

```json
//package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "knex": "0.19.3"
  }
}
```

I run:
`$ jest --config jest.config.js --runInBand foo.spec.js` and I expect there to be a console log of `{ a : 4}`, but it is `undefined`. Note however, if I move the `client` inside `func` then it will log `{a : 4}`

alternatively, if I leave the `client` where it is and `require` `foo` in `spec.js` after `mockImplementation`, it will again have the expected console log.

I would have expected to see the correct behavior with the `client` being created outside of `func` and without needing to `require` `foo` after `mockImplementation`.

Why is this happening and how can I have the desired behavior without moving the `client`? also `require`ing inside the function is not the best.

I created this repl.it for experimentation; please don't update it for others' use:

https://replit.com/join/xmlwttzl-eminarakelian1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of the module scope will be executed immediately when the module is required, so it is too late to provide the mock implementation in the test case.

`jest.mock()` will be hoisted to the top of the test file. It will be executed before the `require` statement, so when the module is required, the mock implementation provided in `jest.mock()` will be used.

Provide a mock implementation inside `jest.mock()` like this:

```js
const foo = require('./foo');

jest.mock('knex', () => jest.fn(() => ({ a: 4 })));

describe('jest.mockImplementation', () => {
  it('should mock knex', async () => {
    await foo.func();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66881537/foo.spec.js (6.347 s)
  jest.mockImplementation
    ✓ should mock knex (15 ms)

  console.log
    { a: 4 }

      at Object.<anonymous> (examples/66881537/foo.js:8:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.789 s
```